# Using Dispose to stop the timer from being called

Tags: c#, timer, reference, null, dispose

**Situation**

I am using a class containing a Timer object to call a method every X seconds.
This class (as it is part of an MVVM concept) closely connected to a UserControl.XAML.

When the user is "closing" the UserControl class object of "MyClass" (incl. the timer) is no longer needed.

I assume the timer object will continuously execute the method `WriteLine("Called after 15 secs")` unit Garbage Collector finalizes "MyClass" object.

To avoid this, of course I can manually implement the Dispose method to destroy the timer object. (See example)

Is this the correct approach?

(Also the question if its required to set `pullTimer = null`)

Thank you in advanced!

**Example**

```
class MyClass : IDisposable {
    private System.Timers.Timer pullTimer;

    public MyClass(){
        pullTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(15000);
        pullTimer.Elapsed += (s, o) => { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Called after 15 secs"); };
        pullTimer.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        // Disposing action
        if(pullTimer != null) {
            pullTimer.Dispose();
            // below required?
            pullTimer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to `.Stop()` the timer and let it be disposed of in the normal flow of things?

Comment: Of course, Stop() is an option.  But actually I wanted to focus more on the concept of Dispose() - As you can see `pullTimer` is `private` and so not accessable from outside the class.

Comment: No code is ever correct when you use System.Timers.Timer, you have no guarantee whatsoever that the Elapsed event won't run after you call Dispose().  Or that it won't run more than once at the same time, the AutoReset property is *true* by default.  Or that you'll notice an exception in the Elapsed event handler, they are swallowed.  Don't use it if you want reliable code.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you - but that is not the main topic - replace `timer` with a periodic task if you feel better ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should call the `Stop()` method of your timer to keep it from firing.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with the answer given by Andrew Morton and Alexander.
Besides you can also disable the time during the time when you dont want it to operate.
**TimerObject.Enable=false;**